# Python date parsing from Amazon EC2 EBS

Tags: python, parsing, datetime, amazon-ec2

I'm having an issue trying to parse a date that's being returned by an EC2 script that checks the last backup of a volume.

I'm getting the current string format returned as a string and I want to parse it into a datetime object but because of the extra characters in the returned string, `datetime.strptime` does not work properly. Is there a way to get the string into a `datetime` object without having to use `dateutils` as I'm having issues with that as well.

This is the date string being returned:

```
2013-06-26T02:01:05.000Z
```

This is my code trying to parse it:

```
startTime = datetime.strptime(s.start_time, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:&M:%S.%fZ')
```

Obviously this isn't working as when I try and print startTime it does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a typo, instead of `%` you used `&`.

```
'%Y-%m-%dT%H:&M:%S.%fZ'
             ^
             |
         this is wrong
```

Demo:

```
>>> strs = "2013-06-26T02:01:05.000Z"
>>> datetime.strptime(strs, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 26, 2, 1, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your format; it's not `&M` but `%M`:

```
datetime.strptime(t, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
```

The corrected format works just fine:

```
>>> t = '2013-06-26T02:01:05.000Z'
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime(t, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:&M:%S.%fZ')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Libraries/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '2013-06-26T02:01:05.000Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:&M:%S.%fZ'
>>> datetime.strptime(t, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 26, 2, 1, 5)
```